# What's the music that plays at the end of ep. 22 of Shigatsu wa Kimi no Uso?

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

What's the music that plays at the end of ep. 22 of *Shigatsu wa Kimi no Uso*, when Arima is reading Kaori's letter?

I saw this anime a long time ago and want listen this music now, but I can't find it.

Comment: IIRC it's a show-specific piece, but I'd have to dig around for the title.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9J6FbC9n_Ek) bears some similarity to the segment used, but the instrumentation is different and I am not completely convinced that it is the same thing.

Comment: The moment when you casually look at Anime Exchange, then you see this topic and a wound you thought closed opens again :'(

Answer (score 5):

The piece is called "31 - Kimi ga Iru"
It is in the OST album for the anime, Disc 1.

Followed by "05 - Kirameki ~Kousei to Kaori no Ensou Ver.~" from the ED single "Kirameki" album.

So basically it starts off as Kimi ga Iru, then Kirameki chimes in.

The piece before that is "17 - Kouiu Kimochi wo Nante Itta Kana" if you're interested.